# Avro data not appearing in ksql query

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I am trying to set up a topic with an avro schema on confluent platform (with docker).

My topic is running and I have messages.

I also configured the avro schema for the value for this specific topic:
[image: avro]

Thus, I can't use the data from for example ksql.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

EDIT 1:
So what I expect is:
From the confluent platform, on the topic view, I expect to see the value in a readable format (not Avro), when the schema is in the registry.

From KSQL, I tried to create a Stream with the following command:

```
CREATE STREAM hashtags
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='mytopic',
        VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

But when I try to visualize my created stream, no data are showing up.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Is it that the message is not displayed as you are expecting it? Or have you tried using it with ksqlDB and had a problem? If so please detail :)

Comment: I edited my post accordingly, with ksqlDB no data are showing up, so I suspect that my message are not deserialized properly.

Comment: By default, ksql reads from the end of the topic, not existing records. You need to set a property to change this. If you think it's a deserialization issue, you'd actually see log messages saying so